# How do you get a subset of a python arrow_dataset Dataset based on a list of indices?

Tags: python, pyarrow

How do you get a subset of a python arrow_dataset Dataset based on a list of indices?

```
<class 'datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset'>
```

Comment: Does this specifically relate to [pyarrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/index.html)?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but I stumbled across this issue as well and here's how I solved it, using `transformers==4.29.2` and `datasets==2.12.0`.

The class `datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset` is a `pyarrow` wrapper pertaining to the `Hugging Face Transformers` [library](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v1.5.0/_modules/datasets/arrow_dataset.html). Below you can find 2 code examples of how you can subset data.

**Load example dataset**

```
from datasets import load_dataset, Dataset

# Load example dataset
dataset_name = "glue"  # GLUE Benchmark is a group of nine classification tasks on sentences or pairs of sentences
task = "mnli"  # (Multi-Genre Natural Language Inference) Determine if a sentence entails, contradicts or is unrelated to a given hypothesis
dataset = load_dataset(dataset_name, task)

train_data = dataset['train']
print(type(train_data))  # <class 'datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset'>
print(train_data.shape)  # (392702, 4)
```

1. **Using [`Dataset.select()`](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.12.0/en/package_reference/main_classes#datasets.Dataset.select)**

Dataset subsetting based on row indices

```
subset_train_data = train_data.select(range(500))
print(type(subset_train_data))  # <class 'datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset'>
print(subset_train_data.shape)  # (500, 4)

subset_train_data = train_data.select([1, 2, 898, 94954])
print(type(subset_train_data))  # <class 'datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset'>
print(subset_train_data.shape)  # (4, 4)
```

2. **Using [`Dataset.filter()`](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.12.0/en/package_reference/main_classes#datasets.Dataset.filter)**

Filter rows based on conditions

```
subset_train_data = train_data.filter(lambda x: x["label"] == 1)
print(type(subset_train_data))  # <class 'datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset'>
print(subset_train_data.shape)  # (130900, 4)
```

**Note:** You could also convert your `datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset` into a `pandas.DataFrame` using [`.to_pandas()`](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.12.0/en/package_reference/main_classes#datasets.Dataset.to_pandas), apply your subsetting logic using `pandas` syntax, and subsequently convert your subsetted dataframe back to `datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset` using [`.from_pandas()`](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.12.0/en/package_reference/main_classes#datasets.Dataset.from_pandas)

Answer (score 0):

[Dataset.take](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.Dataset.html#pyarrow.dataset.Dataset.take) returns a table from a list/array of indices.